# Decode RabbitMQ Message values

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

I use a RabbitMQ Queue to transport messages from a system to a python (3.5) script. The message includes a tuple with several values and is representated like this:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x04test\x00\x00\x00\x06 test2'
```

Alternatively I can seperate the values by commas. The values contain actually a row of an csv file. This means that a string could contain a comma that is masked also. Example:

```
"string 1", "string 2, additional info", "also, only, one, string", 1234, "1,2,3,4"
```

Is there a good way to seperate the values and store it in a list? Of course I can do a decode, a split (comma) etc. but that is not a really handy. Any ideas?

Comment: if you have control over the producer ( not the python script, the other component that is putting messages into the queue ), you could use a serialization library like json or msgpack. encode before publishing and decode on receiving. it will take care of the escaping commas etc.

Comment: @algrebe: Ha! I was thinking all the time about a RabbitMQ related function (and I would be still interessted in that if it exists) but sure, this would save the problem as well... I will try that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Stefan RabbitMQ is a message broker. What these messages are/contain, beyond a sequence of bytes, is not the brokers concern.

Comment: I come up with this solution: I send messages in JSON format to the queue, so its easy to convert and use everything. Thank you for the ideas.